# How we add custom text in front page in magento 1.9 via custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento , I have created a simple custom module and access that module via browser and its working fine .Now my question is , i have to display some custom text in **frontend\base\default\template\page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml** file via my previously created
custom module.Can you please suggest , how we achieve this in magento 1.9.

Comment: You want to change the breadcrumbs.phtml only in that page or everywere in your frontend?

Comment: Everywhere in my front-end , i know how to change directly in that file but i need that changes via module .Just display some text in that file ( in front-end ) is enough for me.

Comment: The only thing that you can do if you dont want to rewrite the Phtml is use the Layout to print before or after the breadcrumbs, to change something inside the Phtml itself there's no other way as i know if not rewriting it with custom template, i dont have clear if you want to add text inside the breadcrumb like adding a new link or something, in that case you would have to check the breadcrumb.php inside /catalog/block/Breadcrumbs.php